# Android: Changing an ImageView src depending on database field data

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android development (started 2 days ago) and have been through a number of tutorials already.  I'm building a test app from the NotePad exercise ([Link to tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)) in the Android SDK and as part of the list of notes I want to display a different image depending on the contents of a database field i've called "notetype".  I'd like this image to appear in the List view before each notepad entry.

The code in my .java file is:

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();

    notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NOTENAME, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NOTETYPE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.note_name, R.id.note_type};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

And my layout xml file (notes_row.xml) looks like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/note_type"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/default_note"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/note_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I just really have no clue how I'd go about fetching the right drawable depending on the type of note that has been selected.  At the moment I have the ability to select the type from a Spinner, so what gets stored in the database is an integer.  I've created some images that correspond to these integers but it doesn't seem to pick things up.

Any help would be appreciated.  If you need more info then please let me know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You might want to try using a ViewBinder. http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html

This example should help:

```
private class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch(viewId) {
            case R.id.note_name:

                TextView noteName = (TextView) view;
                noteName.setText(Cursor.getString(columnIndex));

            break;
            case R.id.note_type:

                ImageView noteTypeIcon = (ImageView) view;

                int noteType = cursor.getInteger(columnIndex);
                switch(noteType) {
                    case 1:
                        noteTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        noteTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
                    break;
                    etc…
                }

            break;
        }
    }
```

}

Then add it to your adapter with

```
note.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
```

Comment: Excellent - works perfect.  Couldn't have asked for an easier solution :).  You have my sincere thanks!

Comment: I would like to add that you don't have to cover all cases in the `setViewValue`, just for ImageView. For all other Views you should just return `false` and in this case Android will apply normal binding that you supplied to SimpleCursorAdapter.