# How to differentiate read and unread messages in android ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

`SimpleCursorAdapter` is used in my code.
Cursor contains field `read` (true/false).
If it is true, then row should be shown with grey text color, if false - with white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as easy as that you've written you can use setViewBinder/setViewValue in your SimpleCursorAdapter. The following will show a TextView of the row-layout that get's painted in red if a column in your cursor holds some value of interest to you. If there are more fields you need to apply some minor changes. return true if you set own values, return false if Android should paint:

```
... create SimpleCursorAdapter
if (simpleCursorAdapter != null) {
  simpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) view;

      long l = cursor.getLong(positionOfReadValue);
      if (l == valueOfRead) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      }

      return false;
    }

  } );

  setListAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @hjw. Can I use the same approach for icon (it will display whether item is read or not)? Or it will not be efficient with icon?

Comment: Sure, you can create a Drawable in onCreate, add an ImageView to your row-layout and set the Drawable whenever another field in your cursor has a value of interest.

Comment: How should I change the following line - `TextView textView = (TextView) view;`, if each row of my listview has 2 items - icon and textview?

Comment: Found that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192082/android-changing-an-imageview-src-depending-on-database-field-data