# Android Hello GridView Tutorial Will Not Display Images

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-gridview

First time poster!

I am new to Android development and have been following Google's HelloView tutorials without problems... until the HelloGridView tutorial. For some reason I cannot get any images to display, only a black background. I originally followed this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

but moved on to this nearly identical one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

in order to eliminate some added complexity by removing the OnItemClickListener code and narrow my possible problem areas. My code is exactly the same as the provided code, literally copied and pasted. I even downloaded the original sample files from the tutorial and placed them in the res\drawable folder, and the R code appears to have recognized them successfully and updated it's generated code accordingly. I am using Android target 1.5 and have tried this program both on my Droid X and using the Android emulator. I have all of my imports and the code compiles and runs fine. However, my activity displays only a black screen; no images appear. When I click on the black background, orange squares appear where the images should be. I found one or two posts mentioning this problem, but it was always coupled with some larger, more obvious problem and never addressed. I will list my code and LogCat below for reference.

I noticed that my LogCat mentioned:

```
WARN/ImageView(364): Unable to find resource: 2130837507
```

which led me to this thread:
[Why setImageResource displays nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443691/why-setimageresource-displays-nothing)
detailing a possible workaround using setImageDrawable instead of setImageResource. I implemented this using the following line of code:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds[position]));
```

however, that just resulted in a Resources$NotFoundException that crashed my code (also documented below).

**IN CONCLUSION**
I figure that an Android tutorial shouldn't require a workaround, so I'm guessing that I have some sort of configuration issue. After a few hours of searching and trying things, I haven't found a solution yet so I figured it warrants some discussion. Also, with this being my first post, please let me know if you see any glaring faux pas. I apologize in advance for the oncoming wall-o-code, though I figure too little data may be worse than too much. :D

Thanks Guys!

*MarnBeast*

**UPDATE**
I tried using R.drawable.icon in my mThumbIds, alternating between that and one of my pictures. None of the pictures showed up, but the icons did. I then tried a .png version of my picture, but that didn't work either. I copied the icon.png image and edited it in paint (put a mustache on the android guy :D) and saved it as dummyicon.png. I alternated between that and the icon, but that didn't work either. Finally, I got rid of all of the icon references, and just used my png image, but oddly, when run, ALL of the images showed up as the icon, even though I am not referencing it in mThumbIds! This differs from the previous behavior, when nothing at all was displayed. I changed a couple to the dummyicon, and when run, those images just didn't show up / were just black. All of the other images (the one png converted image repeated in mThumbIds) still showed up as icons.

Finally, I replaced my converted png image references with icon again, alternating between icon and dummyicon, and now neither of them show up - just a black screen again. So it appears that dummyicon and icon both yield nothing when referenced, just a black space, but my converted png image - chloie1.png - yields the icon.png. I added another picture - chloie2.png - and alternated between chloie1 and chloie2, but only chloie1 shows the icon image. Thus, this is the state of my mThumbIds as of now:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2,
        R.drawable.chloie1, R.drawable.chloie2
};
```

and this is the output from the emulator:

[image: Emulator Display - GridView Problem]

***SOLUTION!***
As it turned out, for some reason this tutorial would not work for me with JPEG images. Furthermore, I made a dumb assumption and simply changed the extension from .jpg to .png, which still worked in image viewers but was still recognized as a jpg by android. Now that I have edited each picture in paint, then saved as a PNG type, everything seems to work fine.

*HOWEVER* I still feel that there is an issue here. I'm assuming that android should handle .jpg images considering that they provided jpegs as their sample pictures. If anyone has an idea as to why PNG works but JPG doesn't, please respond. In the mean time, this simple fix will do just fine.

Thanks for the help!

**REFERENCES**

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

HelloGridViewActivity.java

```
package com.marnbeast.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class HelloGridViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.marnbeast.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

LogCat Unable to Find Resource:

```
07-24 06:00:04.564: WARN/ResourceType(364): getEntry failing because entryIndex 3 is beyond type entryCount 1
07-24 06:00:04.564: WARN/ResourceType(364): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020003 (t=1 e=3) in package 0: 0x80000001
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364): Unable to find resource: 2130837507
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020003
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:579)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:485)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:270)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at com.marnbeast.android.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:41)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:934)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-24 06:00:04.584: WARN/ImageView(364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LogCat Resource Not Fount Exception After Workaround with .setImageDrawable:

```
    07-24 07:02:50.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020003
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:579)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at com.marnbeast.android.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:40)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:934)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-24 07:02:50.245: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:** I'm including the R file to verify that the images are correctly referenced.

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.marnbeast.android;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
        public static final int sample_0=0x7f020001;
        public static final int sample_1=0x7f020002;
        public static final int sample_2=0x7f020003;
        public static final int sample_3=0x7f020004;
        public static final int sample_4=0x7f020005;
        public static final int sample_5=0x7f020006;
        public static final int sample_6=0x7f020007;
        public static final int sample_7=0x7f020008;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int gridview=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any recourses in the `res/drawable`-folder?

Comment: Yes I have the 8 sample jpeg images provided by the tutorial, sample_0.jpg to sample_7.jpg, plus the icon.png that was already in the drawable folder.

Comment: The `sample_2`-image seams to be the problems cause. Can you check if the file is there/corrupt and try changing something in the `res`-folder so the `R.java` gets recreated?

Comment: Ok, I renamed the sample_2.jpg to renamed_sample_2.jpg and updated the imageAdapter mThumbIds with this change as well. I also double clicked the image to verify that it was not corrupt and it displayed successfully in my default image viewer. R.java automatically changed in response:

        public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
        public static final int renamed_sample_2=0x7f020001;
        public static final int sample_0=0x7f020002;

However, the same problem appears. Logcat says Failure getting entry for 0x7f020004

Comment: Also, I noticed that LogCat is initially giving me ResourceType warnings saying "Resources don't contain package for resource number 0xf0700e5" and again for 0xf7f020031, 0xf7f020030, 0xf7f050000, 0xf7f060000, and 0xf7f060001. Furthermore, the warnings described in my post and above comment are repeated for each image - (20001, 20002, 20005, 20006, 20007, 20008, 20003, 20004)

Comment: I added an update to the post that includes some experimentation with other images with interesting results.

Comment: It works well for me. I have tried to reproduce that behavior by manually corrupting the images. It worked in that it doesn't display the images but I can't reproduce the logcat error message. Have you _zipaligned_ the APK or used the `Export Wizard`?

Comment: Congratulations on fixing it and welcome to SO!

You should copy your solution as a new answer and accept it, however, so that this question appears closed... and people like me aren't lured here by an unanswered question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use this code,

```
public class MyGridView extends Activity { 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.animalsgridview);
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewid);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        int imageId = ((ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).mygetItemId(position);

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),Full.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra(Full.class.getName(),imageId);
        AnimalsGridView.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);         
        }
    });
}
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return imagearray.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return imagearray[position];
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(imagearray[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
    // references to our images                    
    private Integer[] imagearray = {                 

        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7

        };
    public int mygetItemId(int position) {
                return imagearray[position];
    }                                
  }
}
```

this is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridviewid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"        
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace your adapter class by given code

```
package com.marnbeast.android; 

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in these cases, a clean and rebuild of the project will resolve the problem. It is possible that replacing the images simply forced your R file to refresh.

If not, my only other thought is that android only supports baseline and progressive jpegs. If your jpeg had some sort of weird optimisation on it, that could have made for an invalid resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a Clean/rebuild of your project please